# Configure Raspberry with lighttpd as reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, lighttpd

I am running two raspberry pis as a webserver (assume it is production and dev-env). Since I am running this on my private DSL line I am running all machines behind a FritzBox router. The router can route traffic for port 80 and 443 only to one server behind the router.
So I want all traffic to be routed to my productive environment.

The question is whether lighttpd (on the productive server) can be used to serve the productive content and also route all requests to the dev environment to the second web server.

I assume mod_proxy will do exactly that job but I want to make sure that I am on the right path...

Appreciate any advise on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some requests, e.g. to /dev/ to go to the dev-env web server, then, yes, you can run mod_proxy on the production server to handle all requests, and to act as reverse proxy to backend dev-env web server for request to /dev/...